# How can I make `subprocess.Popen.poll` work in a meaningful way for remote processes started via `ssh`?

Tags: python, ssh, subprocess, popen, polling

I want to wait for a sub-process to complete. `Popen.poll` should tell me when the process has finished. The following, minimal, working example illustrates the approach:

```
from subprocess import Popen
import time

DURATION = 5
p = Popen(['sleep', f'{DURATION:d}'])
while p.poll() is None:
    print('Waiting ...')
    time.sleep(1)
print('Done!')
```

It waits for 5 seconds until `poll` returns a value other than `None`:

```
Waiting ...
Waiting ...
Waiting ...
Waiting ...
Waiting ...
Done!
```

As soon as I add `ssh` to the mix, i.e. `p = Popen(['ssh', 'remote_host', f'sleep {DURATION:d}'])`, I am getting a different result:

```
Waiting ...
Done!
```

`poll` returns a value other than `None` long before the remote process has exited. Interestingly, `p.communicate` will in fact block for the entire duration of fife seconds, even with `ssh` in between.

How can I determine whether the remote process has actually finished, similar to `poll` locally, without using `communicate`? Asking more broadly, what is going on? I am *guessing* this is an `ssh` issue.

Comment: `Popen` only makes sense for a locally running process. Use whatever makes sense on the remote system to manage the process locally there.

Comment: I disagree with @tripleee on this one: I don't think the use of `ssh` should make any difference. You're still running a command on your local machine that runs for the duration of the `sleep` command and then exits. It's not like `ssh` backgrounds the remote task and exits immediately or anything like that. For what it's worth, I can't reproduce the behavior you've described here; whether I run with or without `ssh` the behavior is the same: the poll loops runs for about 5 seconds until the process exits. You can see my test [here](https://asciinema.org/a/ArbvPKlIveWdb3EjTbX1diEkg).

Comment: Can you run `ssh remotehost 'sleep 5'` from the command line? ssh may be exiting immediately with an error for some reason.